# error upgrading grails application from 2.2 to 2.4

Tags: java, spring, grails

I'm upgrading my grails application from version 2.2 to 2.4 and I get the stacktrace listed below. I've found a case in grails jira bug tracking and the issue remains open.

https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11441

Does anyone know if anything can be done on my part? Or, does this mean I'm unable to complete my upgrade until this issue is resolved?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopInfrastructureBean
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1083)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1061)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:583)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:561)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:538)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:517)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.runCompiler(Groovyc.java:1104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:1155)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.Grailsc.compile(Grailsc.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:770)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:319)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:264)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:147)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:203)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder.invokeMethod(GantBuilder.java:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler.compilePluginSources(GrailsProjectCompiler.groovy:378)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler.this$3$compilePluginSources(GrailsProjectCompiler.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler$this$3$compilePluginSources$3.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler.compilePlugins(GrailsProjectCompiler.groovy:346)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler$compilePlugins$2.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler.compilePlugins(GrailsProjectCompiler.groovy:312)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler$compilePlugins$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3_closure8_closure9.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:61)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3_closure8_closure9.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at _GrailsCompile.withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile.groovy:68)
    at _GrailsCompile.this$4$withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1150)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1044)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:60)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.profile(BaseSettingsApi.java:342)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:952)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1131)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1087)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:730)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:78)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1150)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1044)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Build Config file:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

// uncomment (and adjust settings) to fork the JVM to isolate classpaths
//grails.project.fork = [
//   run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
//]

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

        // Allows connecting to MySQL DBs
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'

        // For JodaTime plugin
        compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9.1"

        // So that spock can work with Grails 2.2
        test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0"

        // Fix for a missing class
        compile "net.bull.javamelody:javamelody-core:1.43.0"
    }

    plugins {
        // Server
        build ':tomcat:7.0.53'

        // Testing
        test(":spock:0.7") {
            exclude "spock-grails-support"
        }

        // Metrics, Logging, and Debug
        // compile ":yammer-metrics:2.1.2-3" // Currently broken, but would be good to have
        // compile ":profiler:0.4" // Currently broken, but would be good to have
        compile ":grails-melody:1.14"
        compile ":runtime-logging:0.4"
        compile ":console:1.2"

        // Security
        compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC3'
        // compile ":spring-security-ldap:1.0.6"

        // Other
        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
        compile ":cache-headers:1.1.5"
        compile ":joda-time:1.4"
        compile ':mail:1.0.1', {
            excludes 'spring-test'
        }
        // compile ":ldap:0.8.2"

        // DB
        runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.2'
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"

        // UI
        runtime ":jquery:1.10.2"
        compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"
        runtime ":modernizr:2.6.2"
        compile ":fields:1.3"
        compile ":twitter-bootstrap:2.3.2"
        compile ":font-awesome-resources:3.2.1.1"
        runtime ":modernizr:2.6.2"

        // Resources Plugin
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
        runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think spring-security-ui 1.0-RC2 is compatible with Grails 2.4.  I expect you are using an earlier version.

**EDIT:**

Updating spring-security-core to :spring-security-core:2.0-RC3 should fix the problem.

Comment: I'm using spring-security-core:1.2.7.3. Maybe that is outdated?

Comment: Are you sing spring-security-ui?

Comment: no, I am not. Should have mentioned that in my first reply

Comment: I assumed you were using spring-security-ui since you linked to a JIRA issue that was about a problem caused by spring-security-ui.  My mistake.  I do not know which version of spring-security-core is the first to support Grails 2.4 but I expect upgrading that is going to be relevant, as it would be for spring-security-ui.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Try :spring-security-core:2.0-RC3.

Comment: same exact stack trace, even after upgrading

Comment: You have some plugin or code in your app that is referring to AopInfrastructureBean.  If you show the contents of the plugin section in your BuildConfig.groovy, that might help.

Comment: Also, make sure you are doing a full clean after updating the plugin dependency.  I am able to run a 2.4.0 app using :spring-security-core:2.0-RC3.  At least it compiles and the app starts up.

Comment: I've added the entire buildConfig application. Please take a gander

Comment: just cleaned the application, no luck

Comment: Does it work with a 2.3.9 Grails?  Also we had better luck building the this parameter added to the BuildConfig.groovy. grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"?  Than if target is cleaned after each build our success improved.

Comment: You are using a number of plugins that I do not think are compatible with 2.4.0.  I think all of these fall in that category...

:cache-headers:1.1.5
:font-awesome-resources:3.2.1.1
:grails-melody:1.14
:console:1.2
:joda-time:1.4
:mail:1.0.1
:jquery:1.10.2
:fields:1.3
:resources:1.1.6
:zipped-resources:1.0
:cached-resources:1.0

Comment: Jeff I noticed that also.  That version of the resources plugin has a big bug you should upgrade that or start using the assets plugin instead which is now the default for 2.4.

Comment: @Joe I think you meant "now the default", not "not the default".

Comment: Paul you should try creating a new dummy application and diff the Config.groovy and BuildConfig.groovy with your application for new configuration values and new recommend plugin versions.